# Div width 100% of the screen but still responsive behavior?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I'm trying to set a div the width of the screen but **without using**:

```css
div { 
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

because this breaks the template.

It that possible?

Comment: Can you add your code to the question so we can see where specifically it's breaking?

Comment: div's should naturally be 100% of their container.  If you place the div at the root level of the DOM, it will take up the full page width.  If it's nested down some, then it will only grow to 100% of it's parent if it's part of the document flow.

Comment: Yes, it's right. The problem is that the the div is inside of the container, then the width is the container's width. It's possible ignore the parent's width without using absolute position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the Bootstrap documentation, you have two different types of container classes to work with. One with a fixed width called "container" and one called "container-fluid" which is spanning the entire width of your viewport.

Link to the bootstrap documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container

Code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you all, i had never paid attention to the difference between the containers classes. I'm a backend programmer trying to cover a UI design requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You did not submit any code though I'll answer your question sans Twitter.

Even if the parent element is statically defined all the child elements will dynamically flow (within the parent's limitations) until *you* put static limitations on those child elements.

```
main {bottom: 0; left: 0; overflow: auto; position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0;}
```

All the elements in the `main` element in this example will still dynamically expand to use 100% of the width of the screen, regardless of what *kind* of screen.

Without using the `position` property if you don't set a width a block element like a `div` will automatically use 100% of the available width of it's parent *unless* it is set to float; adding `margin` or `padding`  will *subtract* from the *content width* unless you specify a width (other than `inherent` or `auto`).

I'm going to presume that there is existing content on the page you're working with so unless you can edit the *entire* (X)HTML of the page then there is a chance you'll be forced to use the `position` property.